# Conditionally sum consecutive rows with SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

My data is delivered to me in 5 minute packages. I am reading the status of a device on a second by second basis, and have already built a script to aggregate consecutive rows of the same status using pandas. My data looks something like this.

```
timestamp   status     length
00:00:00    1          38
00:00:38    0          72
00:01:50    1          27
...
```

I am looking to query a full days worth of the 5 minute packages without edges of 5 minute packets being noticeable. Currently when I query across multiple packets in AWS Athena I see consecutive rows of same status are not aggregated.

e.g.

```
timestamp status length
00:04:02 1 24
00:04:26 0 15
00:04:41 1 19
00:05:00 1 11
00:05:11 0 8
00:05:19 1 22
...
```

I want to aggregate the two rows such that the statuses on the edge of the 5 minute packages are aggregated together using standard SQL, such that the above sample looks like the below. Consecutive rows with equal status bits are aggregated into one, with the lengths of these consecutive entries summed.

```
timestamp status length
00:04:02 1 24
00:04:26 0 15
00:04:41 1 30
00:05:11 0 8
00:05:19 1 22
...
```

Is there capability within SQL to return this query as per the structure above?

Comment: The data example for "not aggregated" seems to be the same as for "aggregated".  Please supply the correct "aggregated" desired results example.  Also post the sql that you are currently using to do the aggregation.

Comment: A full days worth? But there's no date part or field in that sample data? And what's the limit for time to be considered an `edge`?

Comment: Please clarify for data point 00:04:02 1 24  is 4:02 the first second or the last second of the 24 second duration?  Is there a prior data point, say, 00:03:52 0 10 ??  or would it be 00:03:52 1 10 ???

Answer (score 0):

This is a "gaps-and-islands" problem.  Amazon Athena supports `row_number()`, so you can solve it with the difference of row numbers method:

```
select status, min(timestamp) as timestamp, sum(length) as length
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by timestamp) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by status order by timestamp) as seqnum_s
      from t
     ) t
group by status, (seqnum - seqnum_s);
```